# Python list encoding

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary which looks like this.

```
{ latex schlüpfer : [455, 'latex schl\xc3\xbcpfer', 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.6] }
```

Why is my list value at index 1 showing in a different encoding?

I've tried replacing it with the key as well as appending it and it always comes out the same.

Even when I go:

```
print key # latex schlüpfer 
print [key] # latex schl\xc3\xbcpfer
```

What's going on?

I'm trying to check if the item exists but the encoding issues appear to be preventing me from doing this as I'm comparing **latex schl\xc3\xbcpfer** to **latex schlüpfer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objects inside a list are printed using their `__repr__` method. this reproduces your output:

```
# coding=utf-8
s = 'latex schlüpfer'
print(s)
print(repr(s))
```

it prints

```
latex schlüpfer
'latex schl\xc3\xbcpfer'
```

Comment: Yes, ignore the words haha

Comment: So should comparing the values be right or will they also be their __repr__ versions?

Comment: the comparison wil not use `repr` (`repr` is just a [short] string representation of an object; comparison calls [these methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encode your entire dictionary by using the follow code:

```
mydict = {k: unicode(v).encode("utf-8") for k,v in mydict.iteritems()}
```

This uses a dictionary comprehension.